# jquery auto suggest with ajax and django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have my jquery autocomplete like this

```
$(function(){
     $("#id_q").autocomplete({
        //source: availableTags, This works.....(static list are working)
        source: function (request, response) {   // This is not working 
            $.ajax ({
                url: '/college-search/autosuggest/',
                data: { 'keyword':$('#id_q').val(), 'page' = 'searchbox'},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset = utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response (data.autosuggest);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }

            });
        },
    minLength: 1,
    //open: function() { $(this).autocomplete("widget").css({"width": $(this).width()+6})},
    //appendTo:$( ".cls_comp").parent(),
    select: function( event, ui ) { }

    });
}
```

and my django views like this --

```
def auto_suggest(request):

    autosuggest = []
    s_query = ''
    spelling = ''
    letters = ''
    lenletters =''
    loc = ''

    baseurl = settings.HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL

    baseurl = baseurl + 'terms?terms.fl=autocomplete_text&omitHeader=true&terms.limit=5000&terms.sort=index&wt=json&terms.prefix='
    if request.GET.has_key('keyword'):
        letters = request.GET.get('keyword')
        letters = letters.lower()
        letters = letters.replace(' ', '+')
        lenletters = len(letters)
    print "==================="    

    targeturl = baseurl + letters

    print targeturl

    if letters != '':
        resp = requests.get(targeturl)
        text = resp.text.encode('utf-8')
        jsontext = json.loads(text)
        autosuggest =[x for x in jsontext['terms']['autocomplete_text'] if x!= 1]

    print autosuggest

    if request.GET.has_key('page'):
        webpage = request.GET.get('page')
        if webpage == 'searchbox':
            template = 'widgets/searchbox.html'
        elif webpage == 'searchboxlong':
            template = 'widgets/searchbox_long.html'
        else:
            template = ''

    if request.GET.has_key('spellcheck'):
        misspelled_word = request.GET.get('spellcheck')
        s_query = misspelled_word
        spelling = spell_check(misspelled_word)

    context = {
    'autosuggest' : autosuggest,
    'lenletters' : lenletters,
    'letters' : letters,
    'searches' : searches,
    'spelling' : spelling,
    'loc' : loc,
    }
    return render_to_response(
        template,context, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

my problem is I am not able to make an ajax call when I type something in the text box with id= `id_q`.

Not able to understand what I am doing wrong..... 
Any help will be deeply appreciated

Comment: Do you get any errors in debug console?

Comment: Nothing is happening in the debug console.... i guess the autocomplete function is not calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
data: { 'keyword':$('#id_q').val(), 'page' = 'searchbox'},
```

It should be

```
data: { 'keyword':$('#id_q').val(), 'page': 'searchbox'},
```

And this makes no sense:

```
response (data.autosuggest)
```

What are you trying to do there? Do you mean `return data.autosuggest`?

Plus you probably don't want to be rendering a template for the Django response - it should just be JSON. You should at least post the contents of 'widgets/searchbox.html'.